# how to create a type of ResultDictionary that can accept this type

Tags: swift

I'm pretty new to swift and their type system. I'd like to create a dictionary that can have a key of a String and a Value of an array of items that conform to the QueryItem protocol.

```
typealias ResultsItems = Array: [QueryItem] //= [Location(), Item()]
// ^^ getting Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
typealias ResultDictionary = Dictionary<String, ResultsItems>
```

I'm not sure if a typealias is the correct type here. Basically I want a dictionary that can be like this:

```
ResultDictionary:
  - dataItems
      - Item
      - Item
  - dataLocations
      - Location
      - Location
```

How would I declare this for a callback like this?

```
  class func query(term: String, completionHandler: (queryResults: Dictionary) -> ()) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typealias should be:

```
// [QueryItem] is shorthand for Array<QueryItem>
typealias ResultsItems = [QueryItem]
typealias ResultDictionary = Dictionary<String, ResultsItems>
```

As improvement I would suggest to use `[String : ResultsItems]` instead of `Dictionary<String, ResultsItems>`

The callback then should be

```
class func query(term: String, completionHandler: (queryResults: [String : ResultsItems]) -> ()) {
```

Or in this case:

```
class func query(term: String, completionHandler: (queryResults: ResultDictionary) -> ()) {
```